# Can't change Memory High Watermark limit value for RabbitMQ instance on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amazon-mq

By default, when the RabbitMQ server uses above 40% of the available RAM, it raises a memory alarm and blocks all connections that are publishing messages.

The memory threshold at which the flow control is triggered can be adjusted by editing the configuration file, but how to edit RabbitMQ configuration file for an instance on AWS?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, apparently. At the time of writing, **it is not possible to edit the Amazon MQ RabbitMQ configuration file**. The AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/amazon-mq-editing-broker-preferences.html) describes editing of configuration files only for ActiveMQ engines.

As an alternative, you could e.g. launch a RabbitMQ docker image on ECS / EC2, or go all the way and set up a RabbitMQ server (or cluster) directly on EC2.

Comment: Thank your for the suggestion, you are right, the only solution is to create a selft-hosted RabbiMQ instance!